# How to order months by name after having converted them from integers?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning Postgresql. I have this table with dates(DateTime type) and orders. My goal is to display the amount of orders done in a month, but I also need to show the names of the months in order.

I'm able to do the first part but I'm having trouble figuring out how to order the months, since I've already converted them from dates to strings. So this is what I've been doing:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month') as month_name, COUNT(id) as orders
FROM orders
WHERE aasm_state != 'cart'
GROUP BY month_name
ORDER BY to_date(month_name, 'Month')
```

Then, I get "ERROR: column "month_name" does not exist".

I know the problem is in the last line because if I take it out I get no error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change to this. As for postgreSQL, you could use column alias in `GROUP BY` clause to "save" your typing, although for general it should not be supported.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month') as month_name, COUNT(id) as orders
FROM orders
WHERE aasm_state != 'cart'
GROUP BY date_part('month', created_at), TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month') --, month_name
ORDER BY date_part('month', created_at);
```

Or try this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month') as month_name, COUNT(id) as orders
FROM orders
WHERE aasm_state != 'cart'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month') 
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date(TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month') || ' 2019', 'Month YYYY'));
```

Comment: @MatheusParker -- if this answer satisfied your question, please be sure to mark it as correct so future people with the same question will know it has an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `order by` can just use the column alias:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month') as month_name, COUNT(id) as orders
FROM orders
WHERE aasm_state <> 'cart'
GROUP BY month_name
ORDER BY month_name;
```

The problem in your query is the expression on `month_name`.  You would have still gotten a type-conversion error (I think) if the code ran.

So, `month_name` can be used in `ORDER BY`.  However, it cannot be used in an expression.

The simplest way to order chronologically is:

```
order by min(created_at)
```

Comment: When I do that it orders the months alphabetically. I need them to show like january, february... I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.